# Stop console input using scanf()

Tags: c, io, scanf

I am a Java programmer, but currently solving some online problems on C platform. I want to stop reading input when no input is read from console. Its like this

Input :
1
2
3
4

Output : 
1
2
3
4

But in advance, I do not know how many no.s I will read. As many of you may be knowing that online judges feed input from a file. So how to stop reading data from console when no data is fed from console ?

Sorry for very stupid question.

Comment: Will the input be a single line? Then read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: no, my bad ...post edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scanf reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html):

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF) { ... }
```

[Live demo link](http://ideone.com/inAoy9)

Comment: Better to test against the number of assignemnts: `while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) /* ... */`. `scanf()` can return `0` to indicate some error not caught with `!= EOF`